# condition exponentially less likely per loop pass

Tags: javascript, if-statement, exponential

I want to achieve a condition inside a for loop, which will get exponentially less likely to be true after every loop pass.

Here is a simplified version of my current, linear solution: every loop pass it is x+1 less likely that the random number === 0 and thus the probability per run is reduced.

```
for (let x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    if (getRandomInt(0,x) === 0) {
        // do something
    }   
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

But I don't know how to change the condition so that the probability per loop pass becomes exponential and not linearly smaller as in my solution.

Anyone an idea? Thanks for your time!

Comment: You're looking for `x*=2` (or any other factor) instead of `x++`

Comment: Maybe just use something like 10 to the `x` power in your call to `getRandom`? I believe that's exponential... `if (getRandomInt(0,Math.pow(10,x)) === 0) { /* ... */ }`

Comment: Your current implementation is not linear, it's actually hyperbolic I guess? The chances go `100%, 50%, 33%, 25%, 20%, 16.66%, ...`

Comment: Good point @Klaycon, you're right. Thanks for this hint. But I'm just wondering how a correct linear increase would look like in this example?

Comment: @iamrobin. Perhaps the condition would be `getRandomInt(0,9) >= x`. Then the chance would go `100%, 90%, 80%, 70%, ...`, since at `x=3` for example you have 7 possible integers which fulfill the requirement (3,4,5,6,7,8,9) and 3 which don't (0,1,2) giving a total chance of 7/10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of increasing `x` by adding, increment it by multiplying.

```
for (let x = 1; x < 128; x *= 2) {
    if (getRandomInt(0, x) == 0) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't "increment" mean "add 1"? I'd say "increase".

Comment: Maybe. The dictionary defines it as "cause a discrete increase in".

Answer (score 0):

If i understand what you are looking for couldn't you just do following?

```
for (let x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    if (getRandomInt(0,Math.pow(2, x)) === 0) {
        // do something
    }   
}
```

Comment: That's not the correct syntax for exponentiation in JS.

Comment: @Barmar I know that but it gets the point across. Will update now

Comment: Now it's quadratic, not exponential

Comment: @Bergi Quadratic is exponential

Comment: @Maxqueue Uh, [no](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial).

Comment: You were right the first time, just need to use the correct syntax: `Math.pow(2, x)`

Comment: @Barmar That's not what he wrote the first time - it was `x^2` not `2^x`. Which, as Bergi is saying, is quadratic and not exponential.

Comment: Right. Exponential should be 1, 2, 4, 8, ... This is 1, 4, 9, 16, ...

Comment: ...Actually in the original question I believe the probability follows a hyperbolic curve, not a linear one... my math is too rusty to label the graph `1/(x^2)`.

Comment: I stand corrected. I thought quadratic was in the set of exponential functions.

Comment: Note that you've currently written `2*x` which is still linear (hyperbolic)? as it's not raising anything to an exponent - you need `Math.pow(2, x)` as written in Barmar's previous comment

Comment: @Klaycon y=2x is exponential btw

Comment: @Maxqueue that is linear.